# My Tweets are not being received by the person concerned

Tags: twitter

When I specifically tweet to a person B or tweet a pic mentioning the person's Twitter id (@id) the person B is not receiving my tweets in his home page unless the person follows me. When I specifically tweet to a person, they should receive my tweets, right? Why does this issue occur? I checked by creating two Twitter accounts.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not how Twitter works.

If and only if a person is following you, then your Tweets will show up in his/her news feed.

If you put @id into a Tweet, then the person will only see if it:

- The person is following you, or someone else they are following sees
  it and retweets,
- The person looks at the Connect tab in his/her Twitter application.

If you want to guarantee that a person will see your Twitter-message, then use a Direct message - but you can only send these to your followers.

Comment: Ya i Know that but When I tweet by using @id the person should receive it whether they follow me or i follow them is it? But the person is not receiving. I checked with my friend and also I created another account and checked it.

Comment: When i reply to the persons tweet or pic i can see the tweet but others or even that person could not see my reply tweet. but if they visit my page they can see my repy tweet to the original tweet. why this occurs? This is diff none would have faced this issue.